# How to create cookie via Wordpress REST

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I need to update cookie via Wordpress REST

I have function and register route.

```
const COOKIE_NAME = "wts_wishlist";

setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, "Empty-wishlist", time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/' );
//cookie was created in browser

add_action('init', function () {
    //Add to wishlist
    function wts_add_to_wishlist()
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        if(!isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME])) {
            return 'Cookie with name "' . COOKIE_NAME . '" does not exist...';
        } else {
            setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, $id, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/' );
//not changed
            return "Product with id {$id} was added to your wishlist";
        }
    }
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
//POST - Wishlist from cookies
    register_rest_route('wts/v1', 'wishlist/add', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'wts_add_to_wishlist',
    ]);
}
```

example.com/wp-json/wts/v1/wishlist/add?id=1763 returns 200 with message. But cookie not updated in browser

Comment: _“and example.com/wp-json/wts/v1/wishlist/add?id=1763 returns null”_ - when? When you call this URL directly via your browser address bar …? Well that would be a GET request then, you set up your route for POST …

Comment: You don’t find cookies in $_COOKIE, that you just set in the same script instance. The new cookie will only be found in there in the next request, when the client has send that cookie back to the server.

Comment: Hello. I'm testing with Insomnia. I can change return value, but cookie not created in browser.                                                                                       
   `//Add to wishlist
    function wts_add_to_wishlist()
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        //$wishlist_array = [$id];
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['wts_wishlist'])) {
            setcookie("wts_wishlist", $id, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/' );
        }
        return "Product with id {$id} was added to your wishlist";
    }

Comment: _“I'm testing with Insomnia”_ - unless you are trying to convey information about a personal health issue here, I don’t know what that means. _“but cookie not created in browser”_ - then start by checking (browser dev tools, network panel) if the response contains a `set-cookie` header at all, and if so, with what values.

Comment: https://insomnia.rest/ is program for test requests. For checking created cookie I see Dev tools > Application - Cookies http://prntscr.com/pbafz6 (screenshot)

Comment: These are the cookies your browser has already accepted and stored. That’s not what and where I asked you to check.

Comment: Hi. I can't find in dev tools set-cookie response. I've updated question.

Comment: Is this insomnia thing running in the browser, and/or sharing its cookies somehow?

Comment: Insomnia is soft and yes it show cookie http://i.prntscr.com/soz-rRhuR9iEkSYR0mikbA.png (screenshot) I develop site in local server

Comment: So you are setting the cookie with the `Empty-wishlist` value every time? _And_ one with the same name holding an ID, if this route was hit?

Comment: First time cookie will create: if(!isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME])) { setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, "Empty-wishlist", time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/'); } after response i need update value of this cookie if(!isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME])) { return 'Cookie with name "' . COOKIE_NAME . '" does not exist...'; } else { setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, $id, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/' ); return "Product with id {$id} was added to your wishlist"; }

Comment: And which of the two responses are you getting for that? “Does not exist”, or “Product with id ... was added”?

Comment: “Product with id ... was added”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got error when I copied your code and try to check in my local server. I've made some changes and I got working it well.

```
const COOKIE_NAME = "wts_wishlist";

setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, "Empty-wishlist", time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/' );
//cookie was created in browser

add_action('init', function () {
    //Add to wishlist
    function wts_add_to_wishlist() {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        if(!isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME])) {
            return 'Cookie with name "' . COOKIE_NAME . '" does not exist...';
        } else {
            setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, $id, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/' );
            //not changed
            return "Product with id {$id} was added to your wishlist";
        }
    }
});
// Closed this action
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wts/v1', 'wishlist/add', [
        'methods' => 'GET', // Change method to GET for testing.
        'callback' => 'wts_add_to_wishlist',
    ]);
});
// Closed this action
```

In case you wish to use POST change POST instead of GET in methods and try to test with POSTMAN.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Hi. You can test here http://woo.dusmatoff.ru/wp-json/wts/v1/wishlist/add?id=1763 Postman shows new cookie http://prntscr.com/pbn8hk (screenshot) but I can't find new cookie value in browser http://prntscr.com/pbn8xs

Comment: It's throwing 404 no route found. This is what I get result from my localhost https://prnt.sc/pbnj73

Comment: I think you're using POST method and getting data through $_GET variable. Can you please let me know how you make call on API? I mean you're using mobile app to call API or through cURL or something else?

Comment: I'm using postman and browser on windows. Now it's working. How can i update cookie value for all requests? For example 2 requests with parameters 1,2. Then cookie must be array with {1,2}

Comment: Glad that it works for you. Please mark the answer as accept.

To store array in cookie use array variable instead of simple $id. To do this You have to
1. declare variable $val = array():
2. if cookie variable already has value get cookie into $val
3. push new id into array again.
4. set cookie again using cookie value
In above case I forget to write to convert array into JSON to save and convert JSON to array when you get using $_COOKIE

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Did you get through array into cookie? Do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution:

```
function wpb_cookies_tutorial1() { 

$visit_time = date('F j, Y  g:i a');

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$wpb_visit_time])) {

// set a cookie for 1 year
setcookie('wpb_visit_time', $current_time, time()+31556926);
}

}
```